# coldfusion FTP not closing connections

Tags: coldfusion, ftp

CF 9,10,11

connecting FTPs to a server, and using the 'close' tag does NOT close the connection.

I have been able to confirm this by checking a server I have access to - This is resulting in us running out of connections. The client "could" set a timeout; however, the client does NOT want to timeout connections to alleviate a problem on MY end.

Has anyone see this, have a fix? Sees like a bug.

```
<cfftp
    action="open"
    connection="x"
    server="knownServer"
    secure="yes"
    username="me"
    password="mypass" />

<cfftp 
    action="close" 
    connection="x" />
```

If I terminal service into the server, it shows 'x' open connections....(x = however many times I refreshed the page).

Comment: You should be able to dump out the #cfhttp# variable `<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">`  ... see if there is a "succeeded" attribute or any other cludes.  You might also try adding "throwonError" as an attribute to your close command.

Comment: I suggest that you try another cfftp action, such as listDir, after you close the connection.  Maybe you are misinterpreting your observations.

Comment: Dump `cfftp` after each tag to see the the result of the action. And always use a `cftry cffinally` block to close the connection regardless  of occuring errors.

Comment: I like @AlexanderKwaschny suggestion as well. try catch with throwonerror=yes might do the trick eh?

Answer (score 0):

By adding the "close" inside the catch, I was able to make sure the connection closed. Thanks for the suggestions.